# JS/jquery: how would I iterate through each image in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming. I'm currently trying to use the jqueryrotate plugin to try to randomly rotate all the images in my HTML div `.holder` to get that scattered picture look.

I know the $.each function should be used on arrays... but I can't think of anything else to iterate through my images. Any suggestions?

```
$.each($('.holder img'), function(i, value){
    value.rotate(Math.random() * -90 + Math.random() * 90);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array of objects you can access the current using `this`, but it's not a jQuery object, so you should use `$(this)` to chain with `.rotate`.

```
$.each($('.holder img'), function(){
    $(this).rotate(Math.random() * -90 + Math.random() * 90);
});
```

*Reference*

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.holder img').each(function() { //your func });
```

This should work